# Responsive grid like Google Play?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I would like to know if there is a rewponsive grid ui  is around like the Google Play Store (app) is using? Or has someone has an example for it?

I am building a mobile webapp with JQM and Cholatechip ui and I would like to implement a responsive grid ui to fill up the screen..so it look like the Google Play store homescreen (filled with images act like buttons)..

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. Not aware of any Google Play examples, but you can see this website for getting started with [grid layouts](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible - yes most definitely.

In recent years there have been some really good solutions developed to help get you started, with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [Zurb Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) being the two most complete responsive solutions available.

Both solutions are widely adopted in the community with Twitter Bootstrap probably slightly ahead in terms of community resources (E.G., http://www.bootstraphero.com/the-big-badass-list-of-twitter-bootstrap-resources).

If I was going to build a Google Play responsive site I would not use anything but either of these two frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

1140 is very good modern gride now. [Check here](http://cssgrid.net/)